# WPF Entity Framework get the value of the first 2 cells of the Datagrid then change the value of the third cell through binding

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, binding, datagrid, collectionviewsource

Here is what my Datagrid looks like, I'm using a DataContext and a CollectionViewSource in order to populate the Grid.

[image]

Here are the sample codes that I did in order to do this:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="BeginningBalanceViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type reportModel:BeginningBalance}, CreateList=True}"/>

<DataGrid  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource BeginningBalanceViewSource}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BeginningBalanceViewSource}}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Denominations" MinWidth="130">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding BBDenomination, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pieces">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <controls:NumericUpDown BorderThickness="0" Minimum="0" Value="{Binding BBPieces, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Amount" MinWidth="130">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding BBAmount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Here is how I change my CollectionViewSource to update the DataContext (which I got from MSDN):

```
private CollectionViewSource _beginningBalanceViewSource;
private BeginningBalance _beginningBalance;

_beginningBalanceViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("BeginningBalanceViewSource")))
_beginningBalance.Source = _entities.BeginningBalances.ToList().Where(x=>x.BBDateManaged.Equals(d)).ToList();
```

I edited the entity type **BeginningBalance.cs** (which is the **ObservableCollection**)

```
    public partial class BeginningBalance : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int BBID { get; set; }
        public double BBDenomination { get; set; }
        private int pieces;
        public int BBPieces { get { return pieces; }
        set
        {
            pieces = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BBPieces");
            OnPropertyChanged("BBAmount");
        } }
        public double BBAmount { get; set;}

        //public double BBAmount { get{ return BBDenomination * BBPieces; } } 
        //sadly, it returns an error stating that The entity type BeginningBalance is not part of the model for the current context if I ever were to do this.
        public System.DateTime BBDateManaged { get; set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

If you noticed the code, I added INotifyPropertyChanged in order to test things out a bit and see if the Amount (Third Column of the DataGrid) would change (I know what I'm doing is probably wrong please forgive my stupidity as I lack experience in WPF)

Everything is working fine, the only issue I'm facing is that I only need to know how to get the value of the first 2 cells of the Datagrid then change the value of the third cell through binding. The first 2 cell will be multiplied to each other then the third cell would get the multiplied value automatically once I changed the 2nd cell's value. The NumericUpDownColumn is the only non read only and I tried adding an event and yes, it somehow works (but it kinda messes up my way of coding).

Do I also have to create a ViewModelClass for the Beginning Balance? If I have to, I dont know of a way on how to Save Changes on button click which mine is:

```
_entities.SaveChanges();
```

which will directly save to the database.

I'll look into the MVVM Pattern after I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry for being an idiot, it was just as simple as just changing my

```
public double BBAmount { get; set;}
```

to

```
public double BBAmount { get{ return BBDenomination * BBPieces; }
            set { }
        }
```

I just forgot to add a `set{}` damn.

Comment: You don't need a setter - you can bind to a read only property.

Comment: I actually did, but it gives an error:
**The entity type BeginningBalance is not part of the model for the current context**  So I just added a setter and its all good.

Comment: That's a different issue altogether and not related to binding.

Comment: Oh ok, welp, I'm gonna study about this once I get back home.